# C++11 round off error using pow() and std::complex

Tags: c++, c++11, mingw, std

Running the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>

int main()
{
  std::complex<double> i (0,1);
  std::complex<double> comp =pow(i, 2  );
  std::cout<<comp<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

gives me the expected result (-1,0) without c++11. However, compiling with c++11 gives the highly annoying (-1,1.22461e-016).

What to do, and what is best practice?

Of course this can be fixed manually by flooring etc., but I would appreciate to know the proper way of addressing the problem.

SYSTEM: Win8.1, using Desktop Qt 5.1.1 (Qt Creator) with MinGW 4.8 32 bit. Using c++11 by adding the flag QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 in the Qt Creator .pro file.

Comment: In general, floating point numbers are not precise.  They are within a margin of error (epsilon) of the "correct" value.  However, since 0 can be stored in a double explicitly, I suspect that the difference has to do with the formula used to create the result.

Comment: Do you see a different result if you change `pow(i,2)` to `pow(i, 2.)`?  It shouldn't matter, but I'm wondering if somewhere along the path it's choosing the incorrect overload for `pow`, which gained several new overloads in C++11.

Comment: The best practice is to decide a precision (in number of digits) and round the numbers to that precision when outputting them... floating-point are *always* an approximation, so you should *never* think about equality when handling them. My guess about your specific situation is that the stdlib implementation your compiler uses by default special-cases the exponent `2` or the base `(0,1)` while the C++11 implementation doesn't.

Comment: I am removing the qt tag since it does not seem to be a Qt question.

Comment: I too found it very annoying that the overloads for `std::pow()` changed in a *regressive* way: `std::pow(double,int)` does no longer exist, for example. The argument is, I think, that an implementation using successive squaring is only more efficient for small exponents. Btw, I use my own simple (templated) `square(x)` instead of `pow(x,2)`.

Comment: Thx for all the tips, I will be travelling for a week or so before I have time to try it out. Experimenting with a custom pow template seems like a good start!

Comment: i am so glad that this question was asked.  turns out, this behaviour can be a tremendous source of numerical error in complex arithmetic in c++11.  squaring a real number does not produce a real number!!!  writing a simple sanity test `pow(z,2)==z*z`, or `imag(pow(std::complex<double>(randdouble(),0),2))==2` reveals how disturbing this is (at least to me).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11 we have a few new overloads of [`pow(std::complex)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex/pow).  GCC has two nonstandard overloads on top of that, one for raising to an `int` and one for raising to an `unsigned int`.

One of the new standard overloads (namely `std::complex</*Promoted*/> pow(const std::complex<T> &, const U &)`) causes an ambiguity when calling `pow(i, 2)` with the non-standard ones.  Their solution is to `#ifdef` the non-standard ones out in the presence of `C++11` and you go from calling the specialized function (which uses successive squaring) to the generic method (which uses `pow(double,double)` and `std::polar`).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, good to know that it was an extra compiler feature that made it work without the new standard!

Answer (score 0):

You need to get into a different mode when you are using floating point numbers. Floating points are APPROXIMATIONS of real numbers.

1.22461e-016 is

0.0000000000000000122461

An engineer would say that IS zero. You will always get such variations (unless you stick to operations on sums of powers of 2 with the same general range.

A value as simple 0.1 cannot be represented exactly with floating point numbers.

The general problem you present has to parts:
1. Dealing with floating point numbers in processing
2. Displaying flooding point numbers.

For the processing, I would wager that doing:

```
comp = i * i ;
```

Would give you want you want.

```
Pow (x, y) is going to do

exp (log (x) * y)
```

For output, switch to using an F format.

Comment: You're completely skipping what I think is the most interesting part of the question, why does the answer change when configured for C++11?

Comment: All it takes is the slightest change in the run-time library or code generation to produce a one in a quadrillion different in floating point result.

Comment: I'm aware of that, and also of the thousands of other questions on this site complaining of floating point inaccuracy. If this question didn't have some new wrinkle I would have voted to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: It's not floating point inaccuracy; it is floating point _precision_. Maybe your compiler supports a long double type and you can increase the precision.